Draggable items break styles on dragging
I'm creating a sequence quiz and chose @hello-pangea/dnd package (which is rewritten react-beautiful-dnd and I succeeded to create a simple component but I faced a problem that when I grab draggable item it breaks other items styles:
Normal state:

While dragging:

Here are 2 columns:
Left column - simple div with indexes as I received not to create 4 droppable columns but create 1 column where I'll just reorder items
Right Column - droppable column
UPD: I found out that this container has flex with justify-content: center and not full height. When I set it to height: 100% and justify-content: flex-start it slightly improved situation but I want buttons which are not dragging to remain their place until they are affected by dragging button
Components
sequence.tsx:
'use client';

import { UUID } from 'crypto';
import { DragDropContext, OnDragEndResponder } from '@hello-pangea/dnd';
import { useState } from 'react';

import { Button, CardLayout } from '@/components';
import { SequenceOptions } from './sequence-options';

import s from './sequence.module.scss';

export const Sequence = ({
   options: opts,
   title,
   description,
   footerColor,
   headerColor,
}: TSequenceProps) => {
   const [options, setOptions] = useState<{ id: UUID | string; label: string }[]>(
      opts.map((opt, index) => ({
         id: `${index}`,
         label: opt,
      })),
   );

   const onDragEnd: OnDragEndResponder = ({ destination, source }) => {
      if (!destination) return;
      if (destination.index === source.index) return;
      if (destination.droppableId !== source.droppableId) return;

      const newOptions = Array.from(options);
      const [removed] = newOptions.splice(source.index, 1);
      newOptions.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);

      setOptions(newOptions);
   };

   return (
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
         <CardLayout footerColor={footerColor} headerColor={headerColor}>
            <section className={s.wrapper}>
               <section className={s.textWrapper}>
                  <h1 className={s.title}>{title}</h1>
                  <p className={s.title}>{description}</p>
               </section>

               <section className={s.sequenceWrapper}>
                  <div className={s.indexes}>
                     {options.map((_, index) => (
                        <p className={s.index} key={index}>
                           <span>{index + 1}</span>
                        </p>
                     ))}
                  </div>

                  <SequenceOptions options={options} />
               </section>

               <Button onClick={() => {}} size="s">
                  Confirm
               </Button>
            </section>
         </CardLayout>
      </DragDropContext>
   );
};

sequence-options.module.scss:
@import 'styles';

.wrapper {
   @include flex(column, center, center, 12px);
}

sequence-options.tsx:
'use client';

import { UUID } from 'crypto';
import { Droppable } from '@hello-pangea/dnd';
import { DraggableItem } from '@/components';

import s from './sequence-options.module.scss';

export const SequenceOptions = ({
   options,
}: {
   options: { label: string; id: UUID | string }[];
}) => {
   return (
      <Droppable droppableId={'sequence'}>
         {provided => (
            <div
               ref={provided.innerRef}
               {...provided.droppableProps}
               className={s.wrapper}
            >
               {options.map((option, index) => (
                  <DraggableItem
                     label={option.label}
                     id={option.id}
                     index={index}
                     key={option.id}
                  />
               ))}
            </div>
         )}
      </Droppable>
   );
};

draggable-item.tsx:
'use client';

import { Draggable } from '@hello-pangea/dnd';
import clsx from 'clsx';

import { RubicSquareIcon } from '@/icons';

import s from './draggable-item.module.scss';

export const DraggableItem = ({
   id,
   index = 0,
   label = '',
   disabled = false,
   dragging = false,
}: TDraggableItemProps) => {
   return (
      <Draggable isDragDisabled={disabled} draggableId={id} index={index}>
         {provided => (
            <div
               {...provided.dragHandleProps}
               {...provided.draggableProps}
               ref={provided.innerRef}
               className={clsx(s.item, dragging && s.dragging, disabled && s.disabled)}
            >
               <RubicSquareIcon className={s.icon} />

               <p className={s.label}>{label}</p>
            </div>
         )}
      </Draggable>
   );
};

draggable-item.module.scss:
@import 'styles';

.item {
   @include flex($align: center, $gap: 8px);

   width: 220px;
   height: 48px;

   box-sizing: border-box;

   padding: 16px;

   border-radius: 4px;

   background-color: $primary;

   cursor: grab;

   .icon {
      @include set-size(16px);

      path {
         fill: rgba($white, 0.4);

         transition: fill 0.15s ease-in-out;
      }
   }

   .label {
      text-transform: capitalize;
      font-family: $soraRegular;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: $white;
   }
}

/* STATES */

.dragging {
   .icon {
      path {
         fill: $white;
      }
   }
}

.disabled {
   opacity: 0.4;

   cursor: not-allowed;
}


My solution was choose dnd-kit instead
